# Debugging JSR 168 portlets

Tags: java, debugging, portlet

I would like to ask people their testing strategies for portlet controllers, particularly spring portlet mvc based portlet controllers.

Do you use the eclipse debugging function? What kind of portlet container set up do you have in your development environment?

Answer (score 0):

For Spring MVC portlets I simply test them with JUnit. There is usually not much need to fire up the whole portlet stack to test them.

For debugging I use remote debugging to attach the IDE to the Tomcat instance.